# Cross-Site Scripting requirement makes my API useless

Tags: ajax, cross-domain, asp.net-web-api, xss

Maybe I'm just not understanding this right, but this doesn't seem to make sense to me.
I have an MVC4 project exposing an ASP.NET WebApi.  It works great making calls to the API within that project, but obviously making calls to it from another running project (on another port) requires cross-site scripting.

But here's my question:  Doesn't this defeat the purpose of an API?  If I want to make calls to the reddit API from my site, the fact that this is considered cross-site scripting makes it not only a bad security practice, but in some cases impossible.

If XSS is required to do this, doesn't that make AJAX pretty useless as a whole?

Answer (score 1):

**Simple answer:** Of course not!! Pretty much the whole of the modern web is built on AJAX, if it was so pointless it would never have gone from a MS proprietary API to being the backbone of web 2.0 and all that has come since.

**Complex answer:** Firstly, [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) is a form of attack/vulnerability, not a form of request. What you're referring to is the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which limits AJAX requests to the same domain, for security reasons.

[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) is typically used to make async requests to third party APIs. Your *own* API will typically sit on the same domain as your website so you will not have problems. If your API must be on another domain, you can either look at [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) or setup of a [transparent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Transparent_proxy) [reverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) proxy to forward your requests to another server.

Hopefully this all makes sense, it'll at least give you a good foundation of knowledge to build from.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, most apps have had both a server and a client component. The server component would do all the heavy lifting, including making requests to other APIs. Since the API request is done server-side, the request could go to any remote API server. There was never any thought given to accessing APIs from the client, since people expected the server to do it.

In recent years, we've seen more and more functionality pushed from the server onto the client, specifically through JavaScript. But making remote requests is one of the things that couldn't move to the client, due to browser's [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). So its not that the purpose of the API is defeated, its that we are now using APIs in ways we didn't conceive of before.

It would be irresponsible for browsers to suddenly ignore the same-origin policy. This would break the thousands of sites out there who depend on same-origin policies for security. So instead, the W3C has proposed the [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) (CORS) spec. The CORS spec allows requests to be made across domains, but does so securely by letting the the server have the final say in who can access the API. This makes cross-domain requests possible, without breaking existing APIs.