# Web Api hosted on another port on IIS is not accessible

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have two separate projects

1. MVC Web App
2. MVC Web API
   I have published both on my IIS 7.5

My Web App is hosted on 7172 port 
and Web API is hosted on 7171 port

Strangely iam not able to call jquery.ajax() from my web app (7172) to web api (7171) port. It gives me 405 Method not found error code.

But if i write the same jquery.ajax() in my web api project (7171) and call web api method then it work fine and returns data.

I want to call web api from my web app.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your plan is to consume the API inside your MVC application I would rather host it in the same web App otherwise you hit cross site scripting limitations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400710/cross-site-scripting-requirement-makes-my-api-useless

Answer (score 3):

This has to do with the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). By default, you can't execute an AJAX call to another domain (both on name, port and protocol).

If you want to enable this you should use [Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). CORS can be used with Web API by installing a (prerelase) NuGet package: [Microsoft ASP.NET Web API Cross-Origin Support](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors/)

This package allows you to configure which domains can call your service. You can find a walk trough here [Enabling Cross-Origin Requests in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api). In essence it comes down to adding attributes to your controllers like this:

```
 [EnableCors(origins: "http://myclient.azurewebsites.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running into the same-origin/cross-domain security policy. The port used is part of the origin calculation. A bit of Javascript loaded from (say) `localhost:80` cannot make an AJAX request to `localhost:8080`, because the port numbers don't match. The 405 error you're getting is almost certainly coming from your Web App, not the API - check the server logs for the app, and you'll see the ajax hit in there.

Comment: But i have a mobile app (client) which would be calling my WebApi to get the functionality done. In this case wont face the same issue of cross site scripting.